# s.replace string method, looping through a string

Tags: python, string, if-statement, replace, iteration

I am attempting to write a method that replaces every occurrence of a letter after the first as a "*" instead of the letter.
Examples: 
"babble" yields "ba**le"
"that" yields "tha*"

My code seems to be having an issue with the replace function while looping and I can't quite figure out why.

```
def fix_start(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        s = "" 
    else:
        for i in s:
            if i == s[0]:
                if s[0]:
                    continue
                s.replace(s[i], "*")
                i += i
    print(s)
```

Comment: `replace` doesn't replace in place, it returns a new string. I didn't check the rest of your code,  but you need `s = s.replace(...)`

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: As Isaid, I didn't check the rest of your code, so there are probably other problems in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str.replace` method returns a copy of the original string with all occurrences of the given substring replaced with the given new string, so you can simply slice the input string from the second character and replace all occurrences of the first character with `'*'`, and concatenate it after the first character of the orignal string:

```
def fix_start(s):
    return s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0], '*')
```

so that `fix_start('babble')` returns: `'ba**le'`